# Basic R guide: verbatim ? with knitr in R

Tags: r, latex, knitr, pdflatex

I'm producing an introductory R guide for my company. I'm doing a little demo of the R help function (shorthand)

```
?mean
```

This is in a knitr chunk:

```
<<eval=FALSE>>=
?mean
@
```

Output:

```
`?`(mean)
```

I would prefer that it outputs it as I type it, i.e. `?mean` not `?(mean)` (with backticks). Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Apologies if this is a repeat question or has a very simple solution - it's not an easy topic to search for!

Comment: There a bazillion examples in the knitr documentation / site. Have you looked there?  Also, if you want something _verbatim_ and unchanged by `knitr`, you could just use pure LaTeX in that particularly expression and not invoke knitr.

Comment: I've looked, but as I said, I don't really know how to search for that. I could do it verbatim, but I want to keep the way knitr formats the chunk. I guess that best hacky way to solve this is to copy the tex chunk that knitr produces and replace `?(mean)` with `?mean` manually.

Comment: Look at the existing vignettes on your system, find one you like and then at _its_ sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `tidy=FALSE` will give you the result you're looking for:

```
<<eval=FALSE, tidy=FALSE>>=
?mean
@
```

Output

```
?mean
```

Comment: You should also ask @Yihui to fix it.